# Write to Oracle concurrent request output / log from a SQLPlus program

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus, oracle-ebs

I have an Oracle concurrent request that calls a SQLPlus program.  The program itself is working correctly, but I would like to add some logging information to the concurrent request output / log in EBS.

I have tried a number of variations of:

```
set heading off
--set pagesize 0 embedded on
set pagesize 50000
set linesize 32767
set feedback off
set verify off
set term off
set echo off
set newpage none
set serveroutput on

dbms_output.enable(1000000);

--prepare data
EXECUTE program (&1,&2,&3,&4,&5);

--extract data
@"path/file.SQL";

fnd_file.put_line(FND_FILE.LOG,'do some logging here');
fnd_file.put_line(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'do some logging here');

/
```

But everything I've tried so far results with either

- no logging added to request output or log
- no request output whatsoever
- errors like:
  `SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "dbms_outpu..." - rest of line ignored.` 
  and
  `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ENABLE" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ;`

Is it possible to write to the request output or log from a SQLPlus script that is called from concurrent manager?

Comment: What do you mean "concurrent request"?  If you want to spool to a log file from sqlplus you need to add the spool command.

Comment: @OldProgrammer it's an Oracle e-Business Suite question.  I've updated the tags, though I've often wondered whether these are appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem.  The solution is incredibly simple - and now I'm bent out of shape because it took so long to realize.

Step 1 - `SET ECHO ON`

Step 2 - `PROMPT whatever you want written to concurrent request output`

The following sample writes `'Output is written to this folder`' to the concurrent request output.

```
set heading off
--set pagesize 0 embedded on
set pagesize 50000
set linesize 32767
set feedback off
set verify off
set term off
set echo on
set newpage none
set serveroutput on

prompt Output is written to this folder

--prepare data
EXECUTE program (&1,&2,&3,&4,&5);

--extract data
@"path/file.SQL";

/
```

This is exactly what I was looking for.  Maybe this will be useful to someone in another galaxy.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your SQL*Plus script does not even run without your attempts at logging.

1. `dbms_output enable(...)` is missing a dot ('.').
2. Your anonymous PL/SQL block has no `end;` statement
3. @"path/file.SQL` is a SQL*Plus command -- it cannot be embedded in an anonymous PL/SQL block.

Aside from those basic problems, `FND_FILE.PUT_LINE` is only for PL/SQL concurrent programs.  That is, concurrent programs whose executable points to a PL/SQL package procedure and *not* a .sql file under $APPL_TOP.

For SQL*Plus concurrent programs, i.e., running a .sql file under $APPL_TOP, `FND_FILE.PUT_LINE` does not work.  Instead, your SQL*Plus output is automatically written to the request output.  There is no standard way to write to the request log.

If you *really* need to write to the request log, you could maybe call `FND_FILE.PUT_NAMES` to cause `FND_FILE.PUT_LINE` to write to temporary files that you name.  Then, knowing the concurrent request ID and the logic Oracle EBS uses to local output and log files, do a `FND_FILE.CLOSE` and `host` command to move the custom-named files you specified to the actual locations.  That *might* work.

It'd be much better to redo your concurrent program as a PL/SQL package.  Then `FND_FILE` works just fine.  If you know how to call Java from the database, there is very little you can do in a .sql script that you cannot do in a PL/SQL package.

I have not written a .sql concurrent program in years, and I write concurrent programs all the time.

Comment: It does run.  If the BEGIN, dbms_output, and fnd_file commands are removed the program does exactly what I want it to.  You're right about the END missing - I was testing with and without the BEGIN and END in place.  Yes I am missing that dot - I will retry tests with that in place.  Normally I would do all of this inside a procedure or package, but there are some extenuating circumstances around this program that took me in this direction.  Its a valid point through - now that its working perhaps I should reconsider if moving the SQLPlus portions back into a procedure is feasible. Thank you.

Comment: After removing the BEGIN and adding the '.' the program completes normally with expected result - spooled CSV output.  In the concurrent request output an error is displayed - ```SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "dbms_outpu..." - rest of line ignored.```  I have to think that if it can put this error there then there must be a way to add user defined messages in the same place.

Comment: Because `dbms_output` is a PL/SQL package.  In SQL\*Plus, it must be `EXECUTE dbms_output...` or `BEGIN dbms_output...  END;`.  Same with the calls to `FND_FILE`, although, as I wrote, they won't do what you want them to anyway from a SQL\*Plus concurrent program.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for testing/debugging purposes, you can specify the location of the log and output files with the routine: FND_FILE.PUT_NAMES and as soon as you log all the required information you need to close the file with: FND_FILE.CLOSE

Answer (score -1):

As Matthew mentioned, logging in SQL*Plus executables doesn't work well. If you can't move your code to a PL/SQL Stored Procedure for some reason, a Host script might work for you instead. From there, you can execute SQL, e.g. sqlplus -s $FCP_LOGIN ... and write log information as required.
If you just need to prepare data by PLSQL and then spool it to CSV via SQL, you can use our company's Blitz Report instead, which does this more convenient and is for free for such use. It also uses a Host type executable and calls sqlplus from there.